# How to display a login form '/login' instead of 'login.php' or 'login.html'

Tags: php, html, authentication, webserver

How to make my websits login form page to be  "/login" instead of "/login.php" or "/login.html"  Id like my website to only display the directory " /login" .  Any replies and tips are well recieved. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to rename your "login.php" to "index.php" and place it in it's own folder called "login"

Answer (score 1):

[URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

There is existed answer that can solve you problem.

Use URL rewrite login into login.php

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this with `.htaccess` --  This allows `http://exmaple.com/whatever.php` to be seen as simply `http://example.com/whatever`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# add php if possible
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# rewrite other to index.php file
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `.php` and `.html` extension in the url and make `website.com/login.php` or `website.com/login.html` display as `website.com/login` add the following code inside your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

</IfModule>
```

(Not tested).